# How can i optimize this Update statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following update statement

```
UPDATE CONTRACTSF CF
SET CF.PAYDATE = (SELECT MAX(FLHTEMP.PAYDATE)
                      FROM FLHTEMP
                      WHERE
                      FLHTEMP.FLHDATE = CF.FLHDATE
                      AND FLHTEMP.FLHCOD = CF.FLHCOD
                      AND FLHTEMP.FLHUN = CF.FLHUN
                      AND FLHTEMP.FLHCONTRACT = CF.FLHCONTRACT)
WHERE CF.FLHUN || CF.FLHCONTRACT || CF.FLHDATE 
        IN (SELECT DISTINCT FT.FLHUN || FT.FLHCONTRACT || FT.FLHDATE 
            FROM FLHTEMP FT)
```

When the FLHTEMP table has a lot of records (6M records), it takes many hours to complete.

I have tried using IN with multiple columns instead of concatenating it with || but got no difference.

I created a index of all the columns being used (FLHUN, FLHCONTRACT, FLHCOD, FLHDATE) but Plan explain shows me its not being used.

The costly operations showed on Plan explain are a Hash Join, Sort Unique and Table full access

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...` is useless for `IN (...)` expression. Try `WHERE (CF.FLHUN, CF.FLHCONTRACT, CF.FLHDATE) IN (SELECT FT.FLHUN, FT.FLHCONTRACT, FT.FLHDATE  FROM ...) `

Comment: i have already tried that but the performance is the same

Comment: If no other things work(indexing etc.) then I would suggest you to add a new  column in both tables which will store this concatenated value `CF.FLHUN || CF.FLHCONTRACT || CF.FLHDATE`. Try to add that column in one table first and if still no significant improvement then add it to other table too. Basically this will save Oracle doing the concatenation and then storing it somewhere to compare on both table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of an query depends on multiple factors. Such as

- Data Volume of the tables
- Type of access on Joined columns
- Type of table access(Full Scan/Indexed Scan/..)

It is difficult to optimize a query without knowing the table structures and Explain plan.

The `WHERE` clause here is unnecessary, If you don't want to update the records where the three columns don't match then

1. Try updating all the rows of CONTRACTSF: NVL will retain the values where the later joining condition wont match.

   `UPDATE CONTRACTSF CF
   SET CF.PAYDATE = (SELECT NVL(MAX(FLHTEMP.PAYDATE),CF.PAYDATE)
                         FROM FLHTEMP
                         WHERE
                         FLHTEMP.FLHDATE = CF.FLHDATE
                         AND FLHTEMP.FLHCOD = CF.FLHCOD
                         AND FLHTEMP.FLHUN = CF.FLHUN
                         AND FLHTEMP.FLHCONTRACT = CF.FLHCONTRACT)`
2. OR Use EXISTS instead of IN

   `UPDATE CONTRACTSF CF
      SET CF.PAYDATE =
             (SELECT MAX (FLHTEMP.PAYDATE)
                FROM FLHTEMP
               WHERE     FLHTEMP.FLHDATE = CF.FLHDATE
                     AND FLHTEMP.FLHCOD = CF.FLHCOD
                     AND FLHTEMP.FLHUN = CF.FLHUN
                     AND FLHTEMP.FLHCONTRACT = CF.FLHCONTRACT)
    WHERE EXISTS
             (SELECT 1
                FROM FLHTEMP FT
               WHERE     FLHTEMP.FLHDATE = CF.FLHDATE
                     AND FLHTEMP.FLHUN = CF.FLHUN
                     AND FLHTEMP.FLHCONTRACT = CF.FLHCONTRACT)`

Comment: @avjr In addition to this answer, I'd create an index on FLHTEMP (FLHDATE, FLHCOD, FLHUN, FLHCONTRACT, **PAYDATE**) - that way all of the columns in the subquery are in the index (you had missed out PAYDATE in your index).

Comment: @avjr the first statement doesn't behave exact the same as the original query see explanation in the comment of the answer proposing MERGE. Option 2 is fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It requires one scan of flhemp, one aggregation, and then one hash join.

```
merge
 into contractsf cf
using (select flhdate, flhcod, flhun, flhcontract
             ,max(flhtemp.paydate) as max_paydate
         from flhtemp
        group by flhdate, flhcod, flhun, flhcontract
      ) fl
    on(    cf.flhdate     = fl.flhdate
       and cf.flhcod      = fl.flhcod
       and cf.flhun       = fl.flhun
       and cf.flhcontract = fl.flhcontract
      )    
when matched then
   update
      set cf.paydate = fl.max_paydate;
```

Comment: This provides the best performing execution plan, but unfortunately behaves not exact the same as the original query. If the two tables match on the three columns used in WHERE of the original statment, but not in the fourth, then the PAYDATE is updated to NULL. The MERGE doen't change such a row.